# nested json column parsing in redshift

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless, spark-redshift

I have following redshift table column and want to parse each key value pair as separate columns/rows in the table.

```
{"names":[{"name":"bob","months":8,"days":14},{"name":"tom","months":36,"days":0}]}
```

I tried with json_extract_path_text and getting error. How do I loop through this array and make them as separate columns/rows in a table.

```
select json_extract_path_text([{"name":"bob","months":36,"days":0}],"name")
```

Please provide your inputs or direction to implement this using redshift query.

Thanks,Bob

Comment: You do this by unnesting and the AWS page has a good example.  See unnesting on page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html